# Assembly Dosbox Calculator "Operand types do not match error"

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

hello guys I'm trying to kno if the test code given to me was correct or if I did not properly download my dosbox.
the error says "Operand types do not match"
This code was given to us by our online class intructor to test if we downloaded dosbox correctly.
He keeps on saying that theres nothing wrong with the code he gave please help me.
Heres the code.

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    num1 dw ?
    num2 dw ?
    result dw ?
    operator db ?
    msg db 0Dh, 0Ah, "Input your first number: $"
    msg2 db 0Dh, 0Ah, "Input your second number: $"
    msg3 db 0Dh, 0Ah, "Input the operator (+, -, *, /): $"
    msg4 db 0Dh, 0Ah, "Result: $"

.code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; Input your first number
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, msg
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    sub al, '0'
    mov num1, ax

    ; Input your second number
    lea dx, msg2
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    sub al, '0'
    mov num2, ax

    ; Input your operator
    lea dx, msg3
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    mov operator, al

    ; Perform arithmetic operation
    cmp operator, '+'
    je addition
    cmp operator, '-'
    je subtraction
    cmp operator, '*'
    je multiplication
    cmp operator, '/'
    je division

    ; Display error message for invalid operator
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, msg4
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

addition:
    mov ax, num1
    add ax, num2
    mov result, ax
    jmp display_result

subtraction:
    mov ax, num1
    sub ax, num2
    mov result, ax
    jmp display_result

multiplication:
    mov ax, num1
    mul num2
    mov result, ax
    jmp display_result

division:
    mov ax, num1
    mov bx, num2
    xor dx, dx
    div bx
    mov result, ax
    jmp display_result

display_result:
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, result
    add dl, '0'
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
    
end
```

I've tried configuring things but since it's my first time using assembly yet I have no idea where to start.

Comment: `mov dl, result` throw an error because `result` is defined as a `dw` (16-bit value) and you are trying to move the 16-bit value at `result` to an 8 bit register. You could do `mov dx, result` but the issue here is that if the result is more than 9 the printing will not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your "Operand types do not match" error is an **assembly-time** error.
In the `mov dl, result` instruction, the size of the destination operand (DL) is 8 bits and that does not match the size of the source operand (*result*) which is 16 bits. TASM will detect this and you can't run the program.

Once corrections applied, running the program will reveal **run-time** errors.

- you forgot to specify `mov ah, 09h` for printing messages *msg2* and *msg3*
- you don't print the message *msg4* if the user does provide a valid operator ('Result: ' only appears if the user types an invalid character)
- your calculation results will be off because the high bytes on *num1* and *num2* won't be 0 but 1 (coming from the DOS function number in `mov ah, 01h`)

If you do want a single digit result, then make sure that you only input numbers that you know will lead to a single digit result.
For the general case (including eg. 9 * 9 = 81), read [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos).